# Nightwatch: Get text value of an element when hover over it

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have an element on a page that when I hover over it, a tooltip is displayed with text. How do I get the text value? I need to verify that correct text is displayed.

We are using Nightwatch.js

Many thanks!

[element with tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaOBu.png)

[element id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKek.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information?  The HTML code (or relevant part) would help in identifying a method of acquiring it.  As is we don't have any idea as to whether that tooltip is generated dynamically or sits hidden.

Comment: I add a screenshot 'element id' above to show how we identify the element and how we are currently get text value for element

Comment: Still, without some HTML code it's hard to tell how to locate that content in the DOM.  I would expose the tooltip and then inspect it with Chrome's console (`⌘ + Shift + C` or `Ctrl + Shift + C` to see where you can extract its content from.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand the context by only looking at the images, but I think that what you're wanting to do is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/c8xxuxz2/

For that I'd use the browser.execute() function and store the text in a variable so that I could make an assert for it later in the callback. Would look something like this:

```
browser.execute(function(){
    var text;

    $('#[the-id-that-you-want]').trigger('mouseover');

    // Wait a little so that the tooltip appears;
   setTimeout(function(){ 
        text = $('[your-tooltip-class-or-id]').text(); 
      }, 1000);

    return text;

    }, [], function (result) { browser.assert.equal(result, "[Your tooltip's expected text here]") })
```